# How do I set gdb's syntax to intel

Tags: pi-2

So I'm rather new to assembly code and stuff like and I've been reading "Hacking: the art of Exploitation" and I am at the part where it says to change the syntax of gdb from att to intel. Once I'm in gdb and disassemble main the command is: "set disassembly-flavor intel". Whenever I do that I get the error "No symbol "disassembly" in current context".

I'm running a raspberry pi 2, through a remote ssh using puTTy.

Comment: That book is where I first started learning C!   I skipped over the ASM stuff though.  Anyway, the Pi is not an Intel based ISA, it's [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture).  Not sure that is the reason for the error though as it seems to think you are referring to a scoped variable, not an option.  Check `apropos disassembly` and make sure it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, the Pi does not use an Intel based [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) and so this will probably impact whatever you are trying to do in not insignificant ways (I don't know enough ASM to say how much or how definitely).  Which is not to say it won't be possible, it may just require a little [more hacking](https://stallman.org/articles/on-hacking.html) of the concepts ;)

Anyway, the reason you are getting that error is that `disassembly-flavor` is a non-option on the GDB in Raspbian.  Here's output from `apropos disassembly` on an x86-64 (Intel) machine:

```
(gdb) apropos disassembly
record instruction-history -- Print disassembled instructions stored in the execution log
set arm disassembler -- Set the disassembly style
set disassemble-next-line -- Set whether to disassemble next source line or insn when execution stops
set disassembly-flavor -- Set the disassembly flavor
set print asm-demangle -- Set demangling of C++/ObjC names in disassembly listings
show arm disassembler -- Show the disassembly style
show disassemble-next-line -- Show whether to disassemble next source line or insn when execution stops
show disassembly-flavor -- Show the disassembly flavor
show print asm-demangle -- Show demangling of C++/ObjC names in disassembly listings
```

Notice you can `set disassembly-flavor`.  But on a Pi running Raspbian:

```
(gdb) apropos disassembly
record instruction-history -- Print disassembled instructions stored in the execution log
set arm disassembler -- Set the disassembly style
set disassemble-next-line -- Set whether to disassemble next source line or insn when execution stops
set print asm-demangle -- Set demangling of C++/ObjC names in disassembly listings
show arm disassembler -- Show the disassembly style
show disassemble-next-line -- Show whether to disassemble next source line or insn when execution stops
show print asm-demangle -- Show demangling of C++/ObjC names in disassembly listings
```

Not there.  Since you aren't referring to an option, GDB assumes you are trying to alter the contents of a symbol in the process memory -- but there isn't one with that name "in current context" so you get that error.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. I suspected something like that but I didn't really have enough knowledge to confirm it. I have an unrelated question though. Did you ever finish the book, and would you consider yourself knowledgeable in the area of "hacking". This is a very tough book and I've been trying to hold on and get through it.